# How to test react native in app review in dev?

Tags: react-native, google-play

I'm using this package `react-native-store-review` for requesting an in-app review. but neither any modal shows up nor I see an error when I call requestReview().

```
onPress={() => {
                  if (StoreReview.isAvailable) {
                    console.warn('available');
                    StoreReview.requestReview();
                  }
                }}
                text="Write your review"
              />
```

The app has been put in the google play internal test track

and my Gmail is added as a tester

and I've downloaded the app from google play

and I have not reviewed the app before

but nothing shows up when requestReview() and only the 'available' appears in the dev mood.

I also tried this package `react-native-in-app-review` but it makes the app crashes in android, so any other package suggestion or solution would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is putting the app in the Internal test track.